# TwoWay Binding WPF Treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, treeview, two-way-binding

WPF beginner here.

I managed to bind a TreeView control to a DataViewManager using the code shown at the end of this post. Everything works fine when populating the TreeView control initially but I want to implement two way binding so that I can use a textbox to filter out unwanted TreeView items. 
My problem is that the treeview isn't updated if
I'm trying to use something like this:

```
        private void SearchTree_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(SearchTree.Text.Length>0)
            Command.dvm.DataViewSettings["Categories"].RowFilter = "CategoryName LIKE '%"+SearchTree.Text+"%'";
        }
```

Can anyone please help me find out what I'm doing wrong here?!

Xaml:

```
...
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider 
            x:Key="dataVMProvider" 
            MethodName="CreateDataVM" 
            ObjectType="{x:Type local:DataVMCreator}" 
            />


        <DataTemplate x:Key="InstancesTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding InstanceUID}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
            x:Key="SymbolsTemplate"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Symbols2Instances}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource InstancesTemplate}"
            >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SymbolName}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate
            x:Key="FamiliesTemplate"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Families2Symbols}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SymbolsTemplate}"
            >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FamilyName}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate
            x:Key="CategoriesTemplate"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Categories2Families}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FamiliesTemplate}"
            >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CategoryName}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    </UserControl.Resources>

...

        <TreeView 
            x:Name="ElementsTree" 
...

            DataContext="{StaticResource dataVMProvider}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CategoriesTemplate}"
        />
```

The DataViewManager comes from:

```
    public static class DataVMCreator
    {
        public static DataViewManager CreateDataVM()
        {
            return Command.dvm;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this binding for the `DataContext` of your `TreeView`:

```
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataVMProvider}}"
```

Comment: Thanks, but nothing changes... I also tried `DataContext="{Binding ., Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource dataVMProvider}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"` with no improvements.